# When to use application layer encryption

Tags: encryption, web-application, openid-connect

When to use application layer encryption? Is it important in backchannel communication (machine-to-machine) without users?

And e.g. when we create `state` in OpenID Connect's client and redirect the user to an identity provider, shouldn't we encrypt this state parameter? Or when the identity provider redirects the user to the client's callback, why the response isn't encrypted?

Are query parameters enough good to store e.g. `code` safely?

Comment: Please be more clear what you are referring to. In the TCP/IP model (which reflects the reality better than the OSI model) the application layer includes everything above transport layer, so TLS is part of it. But maybe your problem is not the actual layer but instead the parties involved in encryption and decryption - like TLS is between mail sender and the local mail server, while PGP or S/MIME is between the sender and the recipient.

Comment: I just mean in which cases to use application-level encryption. I have also given examples from OpenID Connect to determine whether application-level encryption should be used in these cases or TLS is enough.

Comment: You start off in the generic case. Is your focus on OpenID?

Comment: Let's say my focus is on OpenID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application-layer encryption is a vague term, but the "layer" of encryption is actually not that relevant. More relevant is **between which parties the encryption should be**.

If the requirement is for example that data are encrypted between mail sender and mail recipient, then the usual TLS encryption in SMTP is not sufficient, since it is only between the hops involved in mail delivery and each of the involved mail servers can see the data in plain. To get end-to-end encryption between sender and recipient one would need to use PGP or S/MIME instead.

Similar, if the requirement is that data are end-to-end encrypted between a web client and the application backend, then HTTPS between client and web server is not sufficient but end-to-end encryption between client and backend needs to be used - which is usually implemented inside the application.

Comment: So application-layer encryption provides only privacy? There is no security reason to use it when privacy is not required? I would like you to refer to these two cases in OpenID if you can.

Comment: @Szyszka947: in general: encryption provides confidentiality. Many but not all encryption provide integrity too. But if you just need integrity you don't need to use encryption. You need to encrypt state or code if they are transferred using parties which should not get the real content (i.e. confidentiality).